# nhibernate query criterion api to linq query

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I'm working on custom membership provider and I have working nhibernate criterion api query.
I'm having problem with translation these query to linq. Here's the code

criterion api code

```
 users = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Entities.User))
              .Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Like("Email", emailToMatch))
              .Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Eq("ApplicationName", this.ApplicationName))
               .List<Entities.User>();
```

uncomplete linq

```
users = session.Query<Entities.User>()
            .Where(x => x.EMail == emailToMatch) 
            //missing ApplicationName equal to this.ApplicationName
            .ToList();
```

Update: Figure it

```
  users = (from User u in session.Query<Entities.User>()
              where u.Email == emailToMatch && "ApplicationName" == this.ApplicationName
              select u).ToList();
```

Comment: Change `&` to `&&` otherwise you will perform a logic AND http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from user in session.Query<User>()
where user.Email == emailToMatch && user.ApplicationName == this.ApplicationName
select user;
```

note your criterion mentions "like" to achieve the same in linq use contains allthough this might not be valid w.r.t an email matching

i.e.

```
from user in session.Query<User>()
where user.Email == emailToMatch && user.Name.Contains("Adam") 
select user;
```

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ method syntax:

```
users = session.Query<Entities.User>()
             .Where(user => user.Email == emailToMatch && user.ApplicationName == this.ApplicationName)
```

Note: Only do .ToList() if you really need to run the query right away.